# Video material not rendering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I gave my character his face with a material that uses a video file in an image texture node. In material view, it looks fine, but in rendered view, it does not appear. Can anyone help?

[image: The face appears in material view...]

[image: ...but doesn't appear in rendered view]

Here are the nodes BTW:

[image: The nodes for this material]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible you could upload a screenshot of your node setup, or (better yet), a subset of your file which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @gandalf3 I uploaded the `.blend` file for you to check out, sorry I forgot to do that the first time

Comment: @cegaton I'm not sure what you mean by this... can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the normals on the mesh are wrong/inverted. UV mapping has to be resized and offset completely for the texture to show up and Unwrapping shows an "warning" message. I suggest to rework your mesh and generate a clean UV Map.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Turns out, me being an idiot and all, I made my entire character model on a negative scale. I opened a new file, loaded a character, flipped it and tried the movie and it worked. I have to redo the animation, and go through all of my characters and flip them, but at least it works.

Comment: @Whitest also, you are using an alpha channel to control the mix of two colors, but the video texture you are using does not have such alpha channel. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGn6i.png You don't need the color mix node. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID8ys.jpg